# 3D surface plot from a .dat file

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

Hi I am trying to do a 3D surface plot in python by plotting from a .dat file.  I am having quite some trouble.  I finally have a code that does not produce any error messages, however the plot displays nothing, even though the .dat file is not empty.  My code is below.

How can I plot my data from a .dat file via a 3Dsurface plot?  My data is formatted in the .dat file as three columns. Thanks for the help!

Update:  The .dat file is not empty, I am able to plot the same .dat file with a 3D scatter plot fine, but it  will not work in this 3D surface plot code.  The .dat file looks something like this (just 3 columns of numbers):

```
1 2 6
3 8 7
4 9 3
5 2 5


from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib import cm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.mlab import griddata
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

data = np.genfromtxt('file.dat')
x = data[:,0]
y = data[:,1]
z = data[:,2]

xi = np.linspace(min(x), max(x),0.1)
yi = np.linspace(min(y), max(y),0.1)

X, Y = np.meshgrid(xi, yi)
Z = griddata(x, y, z, xi, yi, interp='linear')

ax.set_xlabel('$x$', fontsize = 14)
ax.set_ylabel('$y$', fontsize = 14)
ax.set_zlabel('$z$', fontsize = 14)
ax.set_title('result..', fontsize = 14)

surf = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, linewidth=1, antialiased=True)

ax.set_zlim3d(0,1)

plt.show()
```

Comment: You might have better luck getting an answer if you post your data, or at least the first 10 lines or so. If you can't share your data, it's best to reproduce your problem with some artificial data (using np.random for example).

Comment: can you check that `data` is in fact not empty by doing: `print data.shape` after the `np.genfromtxt(...)` line?

Comment: @MarijnvanVliet Thanks I tried that just now, It prints out (6561,3).  Note, I can plot this .dat file just fine via a 3D scatter plot, but the second I try to run the same .dat file with the 3D surface plot code, I See nothing on the plot.  Any suggestions?  Thanks again!

Comment: @lanery Okay, I am able to plot the data from the .dat file just fine using a 3D scatter plot though, but the 3D surface plot is not able to plot the same .dat file.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that your problem comes down to a rather trivial mistake you're making with `np.linspace` that I didn't notice when I commented. The third argument of `np.linspace` is the number of points in the array, not the spacing between points (that would be `np.arange`).

In case I'm wrong, I'll show a full working example here (modified from http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/griddata_demo.html), and if your surface plot still doesn't show up when running this example, then it may be a more basic issue you're having with `matplotlib`.

```
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
from matplotlib import cm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.mlab import griddata
import numpy as np

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')

#data = np.genfromtxt('file.dat')
npts = 1000
x = np.random.uniform(-2, 2, npts)
y = np.random.uniform(-2, 2, npts)
z = x*np.exp(-x**2 - y**2)

xi = np.linspace(min(x), max(x), 100) # <-- note change to 100
yi = np.linspace(min(y), max(y), 100) # <-- note change to 100

X, Y = np.meshgrid(xi, yi)
Z = griddata(x, y, z, xi, yi, interp='linear')

surf = ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=5, cstride=5, cmap=cm.viridis,
                       linewidth=1, antialiased=True)

ax.set_zlim3d(np.min(Z), np.max(Z))
fig.colorbar(surf)
```

[image]

Note that your use of `ax.set_zlim3d(0,1)` could also be an issue. I wouldn't recommend setting limits on your axes before you see your data plotted.